# App crashes when getting current user's location (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, maps

My code compiles but the app will not start now. I've tried many variations to simply get a user's current location and display it using MapsSDK but nothing works.

Fragment Activity:

```
class BuyFragment : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private var _binding: FragmentBuyBinding? = null

    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var map: GoogleMap
    private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private val locationPermissionCode = 1

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_buy, container, false)

        val mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireContext())

        return view
    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        map = googleMap
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                requireContext(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                requireActivity(),
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                locationPermissionCode
            )
        } else {
            map.isMyLocationEnabled = true
            getCurrentLocation()
        }
    }
    
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        if (requestCode == locationPermissionCode) {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                map.isMyLocationEnabled = true
                getCurrentLocation()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getCurrentLocation() {
        fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
            .addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
                if (location != null) {
                    val currentLocation = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
                    map.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation).title("Current Location"))
                    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLocation, 15.0f))
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.buy.BuyFragment">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I keep reverting my code to just display maps and that works but I'd like to have the app start on the user's current location.

Comment: Can you provide some stack trace of the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please share the crash log? That will be helpful to narrow the root issue.
Also, if you haven't already, don't forget to [request location permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions) so you can use location services.

Comment: Log:

[link](https://ctxt.io/2/AAAQ1-sYEQ)

But after rebuilding libraries and updating the IDE, then clicking Make Project everything seems to work now. Not sure what happened.

Comment: Based on your logs there's a SecurityException for GoogleCertificatesRslt that seems to a  be related to a Maps SDK legacy renderer (see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228091313#comment44). They suggest to try the latest renderer so updating the libraries may have fixed the error.